# How to write this case statement in query dsl

Tags: querydsl, case-expression

I have a fairly straight forward case statement to write in querydsl:

case when column >= 1 and column < 31 
then 1 else 0 end

I tried the following approach:

```
table.column.goe(Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class,"1")).and(table.column.lt(Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, "31"))).when(Expressions.booleanTemplate("true")).then(Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, "1")).otherwise(Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, "0"))
```

Trouble is, this expression is being interpreted as:

```
select sum(case when table.column >= 1 and table.column < 31 = true then 1 else 0 end)
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying the when clause or to put the goe and lt expressions inside the when clause?

BTW, Directly specifying numbers doesnt seem to work in case expressions. Need to use Expressions.numberTemplate

Comment: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch03.html

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @Niek. Works using casebuilder! But the problem with using numbers directly in case expression persists. Probably a bug. Thanks a ton. Was stuck with this for an hour.

Comment: @AVM What kind of bug did you encounter with case expressions? This one: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/185 ?

Comment: Thanks for saving the life of one more soldier.